# Handle flexible amout of parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've this sentence on my code:

```
.state('category', {
    url: '/categories/:parameter',
    templateUrl: 'templates/common/categories.html',
    controller: 'categoriesCtrl',
    resolve : {
    categoryList: ['Products', function (Products) {
        return Products.listByCategories($stateParams.parameter);
    }]
    }
})
```

It's just a simple web shop, you know... list the products according to categories. The problem is that the number of categories must be dynamic... I can, for example request for:

```
/categories/shoes
/categories/shoes/man/
/categories/shoes/man/running
/categories/shoes/man/running/nike
```

So, the parameter must be dynamic and I've no clue how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You want all those routes to be handled by the same controller?

Comment: Hi ! Yes...anything after the /categories/ is a flexible parameter that can contains unlimited children in theory. I need to point the entire path after the category.

Comment: So just split this parameter by slash and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you have 2 options:

**Option 1(that I don't recommend using but that's an option so):**

```
$stateProvider.state('category', {
    // All patterns may be changed, just remember to keep the {0, x} the 0 is important to allow // emptiness between slashes.
    url: '/categories/{item:[a-z0-9\-]{0,8}}/{gender:[a-z]{0,6}}/{sport:[a-z]{0,12}}/{company:[a-z0-9]{0,8}}',
    controller: function($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
    }
});
```

You will be able to use:

- `/categories/shoes///`
- `/categories/shoes/man//`
- `/categories/shoes/man/running/`
- `/categories/shoes/man/running/nike`

**Option 2(I like it):**

```
$stateProvider.state('category', {
    // Pattern can be changed except the \/
    url: '/categories/{details:[a-z0-9\/\-]{0,20}}',
    controller: function($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
    }
});
```

Now you will be able to use any combination as long as it starts with `/categories/`:

- `/categories/shoes/man/running/nike`

Well now you just have to use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method and then decide that:

1. Key 0 will contain items.
2. Key 1 will contain gender.

And for cases where you or the client input gender instead of item you may check `key 0` against `items whitelist(array with items)`, Enjoy.

Comment: Yeah ! I like option#2 as well :) tyvm, Aviel ! Usually when I've doubts about angular, the community instead help me to find the solution they used to be arrogant and propose change in the ways I build the stuffs...So, thanks to be a humble and a nice guy !

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way I've seen this been done is separating categories with a '-' or a '+' instead of slashes because they aren't directories, and that also messes up most url routers (in this case angular).
You also could look into matching the entire URL and parsing the slashes yourself, but if you use '-' or '+' you could just parse the whole directory as a string then separate based on delimiter to get the list of categories to search for.

Comment: Impossible...first because the categories can have '-' naturally and use paths is good for site map as well and SEO. I really don't wanna go in this way. It's really necessary to use the path format. I built something similar in node.js using regEx that's transform the parameters in array. take a look : app.get(/^\/products\/list\/categories\/((?:[^\/]+\/?)+)/, productsCategories.index);